# Issue recieving JSON with urllib.request

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have been working with a couple of web APIs but this one has me perplexed. I can't work out what im going wrong.

this code works on one api, but not this one.

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base)
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
obj = json.load(reader(response))
return obj
```

this gives me the following errror

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f602' in position 4096: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base)
obj = json.load(response.decode("utf-8"))
return obj
```

which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

and,

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base).read()
obj = json.load(response)
return obj
```

which gives

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

and,

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base)
obj = json.load(response)
```

which gives

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

along with maany other combinations of things I have found in other similar threads on here

I don't remember ever having this problem before, im sure ive missed something but I can't see what.

Comment: one thing to look out for, urllib tends to run into difficulty when it encounters 'invalid' ssl certs on https URIs.  without the proper flags it will fail somewhat silently.

Comment: Are you **certain** you got that `UnicodeEncodeError` from the code you posted? I'd expect `Unicode` **`Decode`** `Error` exceptions. Please post a **full** traceback for your error, but I am pretty sure your code works but you tried to *print* the results.

Comment: ^ good point, i will look into that. although if i open the url with the browser, it downloads the json file and opens it with no problems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahh nice catch, that error actually came from a print statement in the next function (there only for testing as im writing) i guess i have to do something to it before being able to display the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial attempt *is already correct*. If it wasn't, you'd get **decoding** errors.

You have, instead, got **encoding** errors, moving from Unicode back to bytes. This is invariably caused by you using `print()` or trying to write the data to a file object. When printing, this is usually caused by your console not being able to handle the output. See [python3 print unicode to windows xp console encode cp437](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521944/python3-print-unicode-to-windows-xp-console-encode-cp437) for example.

Your second attempt failed because you didn't read the response, then use `json.loads()` (since you are passing in a string now):

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base)
obj = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf-8"))
#              ^         ^^^^^^^
return obj
```

Your 3rd attempt did use `.read()` but you forgot to decode that time, and again did not use `json.loads()`:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base).read()
#                          you didn't forget this ^^^^^^^
obj = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
#              ^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
return obj
```

The last attempt passed in the raw response, without decoding the data.

Comment: when using "obj = json.load(response.read().decode("utf-8"))" i get an error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read', i guess, as my first attempt has worrked with other APIs i guess i will find a way to fix that. thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base).read()
obj = json.loads(response)
return obj
```

This code should work. `json.load` is looking to read from a file stream. `json.loads` is what you want when reading JSON from a string.

Comment: i did try that, but kept getting "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'"

Answer (score 0):

ok, just incase anyone has this issue and reads this thread later

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(self.query_base)
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
obj = json.load(reader(response))
return ascii(obj)
```

worked fine.

thanks to Martijn Pieters